# Getting error on the string im trying to pass to my function call of Createnewfile in main

Tags: java

My only issue is that I get an error where I have commented. Im willing to send my strings (token[]) data at index 1 to the Createnewfile () method in the main. I can't achieve it. Please guide as to what I should do.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


class CreateFile
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {   

    Scanner S = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("FileExplorer");

    System.out.println ("Select:");
    System.out.println ("1.create new file");
    System.out.println("2. Enter text in the new created file ");
    System.out.println ("3.View List");
    System.out.println ("4.Display contents of particular file");
    System.out.println ("5.Delete a selected file");
    System.out.println ("6.Copy files to other directory");
    System.out.println ("7.Cut files from one directory to other");

    System.out.println ("My File Explorer:");
    String phrase = S.nextLine();
    String delims = "[ ]+";
    String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        System.out.println(tokens[i]);

    if (tokens[0].equals ( "createfile") )
    {
        System.out.println ("Create");
        Createnewfile( tokens[] );    //I get an error here, please tell me how to send 
                                                  //the tokens[1] index 1 string to my  createnewfile function
    }
    if (tokens[0].equals ( "entertext") )
    {
        System.out.println ("entering text");
        String St = tokens[1];
        Entertext(St);
    }
    if (tokens[0].equals ( "showcontent") )
    {
        System.out.println ("Displaying contents");
    }
    if (tokens[0].equals ( "List") )
    {
        System.out.println ("Listing all .txt files");
    }
    if (tokens[0].equals ( "delete") )
    {
        System.out.println ("Deleting the selected file");
    }

}

public void Createnewfile( String [] tokens)
{
    try 
        {

          File file = new File(tokens[1]);

          if (file.createNewFile())
          {
            System.out.println("File is created!");
          }
          else
          {
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
          }

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


public static void Entertext(String St)
{
    try     
        {
            Scanner S = new Scanner (System.in);
            String content = S.nextLine();
            File file = new File( St);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to the array reference, just lose the `[]`:

```
Createnewfile(tokens);
```

That's *not* just passing `tokens[1]`, however.

It's very odd that your `Createnewfile` method always uses `tokens[1]` - it would make more sense for that method to have a `String` parameter (instead of `String[]`) and then you could call it as:

```
Createnewfile(tokens[1]);
```

to pass just a reference to the string you want to use to create the file - just like you do for your `Entertext` method, for example.

I would also *strongly* urge you to learn about the naming conventions in Java, and follow them. (So your methods would be `createNewFile`, `enterText` etc.)

Comment: Actually Sir, if i don't send the (String [] tokens), then I'm not sure how inside my Createnewfile method will I be able to access the tokens[1] location.

Comment: @High-Cyber: It's been a long time since I've read any novice Java books, but you might want to try Head-First Java.

Comment: @High-Cyber: Within your `Createnewfile` method, you only *use* a single string - the name of the file, right? So change it to `public static void createNewFile(String filename)`. (Personally I'd declare that that method could throw `IOException` too, rather than catching it in the method and then ignoring it, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use the brackets next to token, send it like this

```
Createnewfile(tokens);
```